# PHP-FPM not responding when CPU is 100% in low priority processes

Tags: php, php-7.2, fedora-29

I'm having a problem when CPU is 100% usage: PHP-FPM does not respond, even the processes using 100% of CPU are running in lowest priority (+19).

Let me explain: my site triggers an audio converter (ffmpeg) using inotify + a bash script. The converter is running using "nice -n 19". So, CPU usage is 100% but, in theory, PHP-FPM has priority (default 0 priority).

What happens: only PHP freezes. Apache can respond to files like JPG/CSS/JS. Linux stable, other SWs too. All .php returns "504 Gateway Timeout" (browser, Apache response). Apache opens a lot of php-fpm instances and keep them open.

```
30585 fedora    19   0.0   0.3   0:00.00 snippeter
30586 fedora    19  25.0   2.8   0:00.10 ffmpeg

15640 fedora     0   0.0   1.0   0:00.12 php-fpm
17174 fedora     0   0.0   1.0   0:00.10 php-fpm
20583 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
21072 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
21309 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
22601 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
23172 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
23277 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
24170 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
24823 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
24916 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm
26589 fedora     0   0.0   0.9   0:00.00 php-fpm

%Cpu(s):  8.5 us,  4.5 sy, 85.6 ni,  0.0 id,  0.5 wa,  1.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Changing php-fpm priority (renice), no difference.

I don't know what to do... I want to run processes  in background, even using 100% of CPU, but keeps PHP+Apache running normally.

Server: Fedora 29, PHP 7.2.

Comment: how many CPU's in the server?

Comment: 1 CPU, it's a VPS.

Comment: Why is it at 100%?

Comment: Running the background processes, but all in +19 priority (nice).

Comment: What kind of VPS? One that allocates you an actual physical core, one that allocates you a fraction of a core, or a "burstable" core that would likely cause this exact problem? You also need to implement acutal _continual_ resource monitoring to illustrate a problem like this as random point-in-time measurements don't exactly paint much of a picture.

Comment: considering the price of hosting, i would just throw another CPU at it, at least to test

Comment: It's a VPS on Vultr, KVM, so, it's a fraction.

Comment: But the +19 priority on high CPU usage processes will freeze php-fpm? I don't understand why only PHP is affected. All other softwares are running fine, getting more CPU cycles when requested...

Comment: * Note: while converting, I have one PHP script running with no timelimit, only monitoring and waiting ffmpeg process to finish, but it almost 0% CPU... can a PHP script running in loop freeze other requests?

Comment: I know this won't answer the question, but in general I'd advise you offload the ffmpeg processing to a second VPS that only handles that, so you don't get in the way of another (seemingly more relevant/critical process such as php-fpm)

Comment: Having said that, your issue *may* not be CPU related but memory related. Ffmpeg uses a ton of ram (probably all that's available) so even if you have more CPU priority for php-fpm, it may be the case that it doesn't have enough memory to even launch in the first place

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this, use another VPS to convert files. But the problem is not related to memory. I'm converting several files in batch, audio files, but all are small MP3, 2-4 minutes, and the server has about 60% free RAM while converting. I just don't understand why only PHP freezes. Some communication problem with Apache maybe, even Apache responds ok to non-php files.

Comment: you could use a dedicated service like  Amazon Elastic Transcoder.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution!

The problem is not related to 100% CPU usage, or just one CPU. Since I have a loop to open each audio converter (bash file), and wait it to finish to run the next one, the PHP **session** is locked! So, when another PHP script, in the same session, try to execute, it cannot read the session file, so, PHP freezes (waiting to have access to the session file, until a "Gateway Timeout" error). That's why only PHP freezes, not other softwares.

To fix, I had to run this before the main loop:

```
session_write_close();
session_start(['read_and_close'=>true]);
```

So, it writes and closes the session file, and read it again once, without locking it.

This only works in PHP 7+ and, obviously, you cannot write any session data. Or, after the loop, just open the session again with `session_start()`.